# Idiomatic way to distinguish two zero-arg constructors

Tags: c++, performance, constructor

I have a class like this:

```
struct event_counts {
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts() : counts{} {}

    // more stuff

};
```

Usually I want to default (zero) initialize the `counts` array as shown.

At selected locations identified by profiling, however, I'd like to suppress the array initialization, because I know the array is about to be overwritten, but the compiler isn't smart enough to figure it out.

What's an idiomatic and efficient way to create such a "secondary" zero-arg constructor?

Currently, I'm using a tag class `uninit_tag` which is passed as a dummy argument, like so:

```
struct uninit_tag{};

struct event_counts {
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts() : counts{} {}

    event_counts(uninit_tag) {}

    // more stuff

};
```

Then I call the no-init constructor like `event_counts c(uninit_tag{});` when I want to suppress construction.

I'm open to solutions that don't involve the creation of a dummy class, or are more efficient in some way, etc.

Comment: "because I know the array is about to be overwritten" Are you 100% sure your compiler isn't doing that optimization for you already? case in point: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bJnAuJ

Comment: @Frank - I feel like the answer to your question is in the second half of the sentence you quoted? It doesn't belong in the question, but a variety of things can happen: (a) often the compiler simply isn't strong enough to eliminate the dead stores (b) sometimes only a subset of the elements are overwritten and this defeats the optimization (but only that same subset is later read) (c) sometimes the compiler _could_ do it, but is defeated e.g., because the method isn't inlined.

Comment: Do you have any other constructors in your class?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - in the specific case that triggered this question, no - although I'd hope that any solution would be compatible with classes that did.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in-scope of the question, but maybe a constructor taking a lambda that actually sets the values of the array directly is safer than using a non-initializing constructor, because it doesn't allow accidental creation of an instance in invalid state.

Comment: @Frank - eh, your case in point shows that gcc does _not_ eliminate the dead stores? In fact, if you had made me guess I'd have thought that gcc would get this very simple case right, but if it fails here then imagine any slightly more complicated case!

Comment: gcc does optimize with `-O3` for @Frank's case. But for larger array sizes it doesn't seem to, no matter the flags. Probably because the compiler can't keep track of the values of all the elements. The same seems to be true for Clang.

Comment: @uneven_mark - yes, gcc 9.2 does it at -O3 (but this optimization is uncommon compared to -O2, IME), but earlier versions didn't. In general, dead store elimination is a thing, but it is very fragile and subject to all the usual caveats, such as the compiler being able to see the dead stores at the same time it sees the dominating stores. My comment was more to clarify what Frank was trying to say because he said "case in point: (godbolt link)" but the link shows both stores being performed (so maybe I'm missing something).

Answer (score 33):

The solution you already have is correct, and is exactly what I'd want to see if I were reviewing your code.  It is as efficient as possible, clear and concise.

Comment: The main issue I have is whether I should declare a new `uninit_tag` flavor in every place that I want to use this idiom. I was hoping there was something like such an indicator type already, perhaps in `std::`.

Comment: There is not an obvious choice from the standard library.  I wouldn't define a new tag for every class where I want this feature--I would define a project-wide `no_init` tag and use it in all my classes where it's needed.

Comment: I think the standard library has manly tags for differentiating iterators and such stuff and the two `std::piecewise_construct_t` and `std::in_place_t`. None of them seems reasonable to use here. Maybe you would like to define a global object of your type to use always, so you don't need the braces in every constructor call. The STL does this with [`std::piecewise_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct) for `std::piecewise_construct_t`.

Comment: It is not as efficient as possible. In the AArch64 calling convention for instance the tag has to be stack-allocated, with knock-on effects (can't tail-call either...): https://godbolt.org/z/6mSsmq

Comment: If you know that the compiler always has the implementation visible, and is powerful enough at inlining to remove it? Sure, this is as efficient as possible. Key word: if.

Comment: @TLW: Your point about it being inefficient on AArch64 is only relevant if the constructors are not defined inline.  In OP's example code, they are defined inline, so there is no calling convention restriction.  You sort of admit this in your second comment, but let's be clear.  When I said it's as efficient as possible I was assuming optimization enabled in the compiler, of course.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - note the godbolt link.

Comment: @TLW Once you add body to constructors there is no stack allocation, https://godbolt.org/z/vkCD65

Comment: @R2RT - at the expense of duplicating the code in the constructor at every callsite. i$ is also not free. (However, on modern cpus an unconditional branch, such as a tail-call to foo(void), _is_ nearly free.)

Answer (score 8):

If the constructor body is empty, it can be omitted or defaulted:

```
struct event_counts {
    std::uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];
    event_counts() = default;
};
```

Then *default initialization* `event_counts counts;` will leave `counts.counts` uninitialized (default initialization is a no-op here), and *value initialization* `event_counts counts{};` will value initialize `counts.counts`, effectively filling it with zeros.

Comment: But then again you have to remember to use value initialization and OP wants it to be safe by default.

Comment: @doc, I agree. This is not the exact solution for what OP wants. But this initialization mimics built-in types. For `int i;` we accept that it is not zero-initialized. Maybe we should also accept that `event_counts counts;` is not zero-initialized and make `event_counts counts{};` our new default.

Answer (score 6):

I like your solution. You might have also considered nested struct and static variable. For example:

```
struct event_counts {
    static constexpr struct uninit_tag {} uninit = uninit_tag();

    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTS];

    event_counts() : counts{} {}

    explicit event_counts(uninit_tag) {}

    // more stuff

};
```

With static variable uninitialized constructor call may seem more convenient:

```
event_counts e(event_counts::uninit);
```

You can of course introduce a macro to save typing and make it more of a systematic feature

```
#define UNINIT_TAG static constexpr struct uninit_tag {} uninit = uninit_tag();

struct event_counts {
    UNINIT_TAG
}

struct other_counts {
    UNINIT_TAG
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think an enum is a better choice than either a tag class or a bool. You don't need to pass an instance of a struct and it's clear from the caller which option your are getting.

```
struct event_counts {
    enum Init { INIT, NO_INIT };
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts(Init init = INIT) {
        if (init == INIT) {
            std::fill(counts, counts + MAX_COUNTERS, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

Then creating instances looks like this:

```
event_counts e1{};
event_counts e2{event_counts::INIT};
event_counts e3{event_counts::NO_INIT};
```

---

Or, to make it more like the tag class approach, use a single-value enum instead of the tag class:

```
struct event_counts {
    enum NoInit { NO_INIT };
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts() : counts{} {}
    explicit event_counts(NoInit) {}
};
```

Then there are only two ways to create an instance:

```
event_counts e1{};
event_counts e2{event_counts::NO_INIT};
```

Comment: I agree with you: enum are simpler. But maybe you forgot this line: `event_counts() : counts{} {}`

Comment: @bluish, my intention was not to initialize `counts` unconditionally, but only when `INIT` is set.

Comment: @bluish I think main reason to choose a tag class is not to achieve simplicity, but to signalize that uninitialized object is special, i.e. it uses optimization feature rather than normal part of class interface. Both `bool` and `enum` are decent, but we have to be aware that using parameter instead of overload has somewhat different semantical shade. In the former one you clearly parametrize an object, hence initialized/uninitialized stance becomes its state, whereas passing a tag object to ctor is more like asking class to perform a conversion. So it's not IMO a matter of syntactical choice.

Comment: @TimK But the OP wants the default behaviour to be the initialization of the array, so I think that your solution to the question should include `event_counts() : counts{} {}`.

Comment: @bluish In my original suggestion `counts` is initialized by `std::fill` unless `NO_INIT` is requested. Adding the default constructor as you suggest would make two different ways of doing default initialization, which isn't a great idea. I've added another approach that avoids using `std::fill`.

Comment: @TimK OK, I've got it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a *two-phase initialization* for your class:

```
struct event_counts {
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts() = default;

    void set_zero() {
       std::fill(std::begin(counts), std::end(counts), 0u);
    }
};
```

The constructor above does not initialize the array to zero. To set the elements of the array to zero, you have to call the member function `set_zero()` after construction.

Comment: Thanks, I considered this approach but want something that keeps the default safe - i.e., zero by default, and only in a few selected places I override the behavior to the unsafe one.

Comment: This will require extra care to be taken at all *but* the uses that are supposed to be uninitialized. So it is an extra source of bugs relative to OPs solution.

Comment: @BeeOnRope one could also provide `std::function` as a constructor argument with something similar to `set_zero` as default argument. You would then pass a lambda function if you want uninitialized array.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
struct event_counts {
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts() : counts{} {}

    event_counts(bool initCounts) {
        if (initCounts) {
            std::fill(counts, counts + MAX_COUNTERS, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

The compiler will be smart enough to skip all the code when you use `event_counts(false)`, and you get to say exactly what you mean instead of making your class' interface so weird.

Comment: You're right about efficiency, but boolean parameters don't make for readable client code. When you're reading along, and you see the declaration `event_counts(false)`, what does that mean? You have no idea without going back and looking at the *name* of the parameter. Better to at least use an enum, or, in this case, a sentinel/tag class as shown in the question. Then, you get a declaration more like, `event_counts(no_init)`, which is obvious to everyone in its meaning.

Comment: I think this is also decent solution. You could discard default ctor and use default value `event_counts(bool initCountr = true)`.

Comment: Also, ctor should be explicit.

Comment: unfortunately currently C++ doesn't support named parameters, but we can use [`boost::parameter`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#named-function-parameters) and call `event_counts(initCounts = false)` for readability

Comment: Funnily enough, @doc, `event_counts(bool initCounts = true)` actually _is_ a default constructor, due to every parameter having a default value.  The requirement is just that it be callable without specifying arguments, `event_counts ec;` doesn't care if it's parameter-less or uses default values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a subclass just to save a bit of typing:

```
struct event_counts {
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];

    event_counts() : counts{} {}
    event_counts(uninit_tag) {}
};    

struct event_counts_no_init: event_counts {
    event_counts_no_init(): event_counts(uninit_tag{}) {}
};
```

You can get rid of the dummy class by the changing the argument of the not initializing constructor to `bool` or `int` or something, as it doesn't have to be mnemonic anymore.

You could also swap the inheritance around and define `events_count_no_init` with a defaulted constructor like Evg suggested in their answer, and then have `events_count` be the subclass:

```
struct event_counts_no_init {
    uint64_t counts[MAX_COUNTERS];
    event_counts_no_init() = default;
};

struct event_counts: event_counts_no_init {
    event_counts(): event_counts_no_init{} {}
};
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I also feel like introducing a new type will cause friction. E.g., when I actually want a uninitialized `event_counts`, I'll want it to be of type `event_count`, not `event_count_uninitialized`, so I should slice right at construction like `event_counts c = event_counts_no_init{};`, which I think eliminates most of the savings in typing.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Well, for most purposes an `event_count_uninitialized` object is an `event_count` object. That's the whole point of inheritance, they're not completely different types.

Comment: Agreed, but the rub is with "for most purposes". They are not interchangeable - e.g., if you try to see assign `ecu` to `ec` it works, but not the other way around. Or if you use template functions, they are different types and end with with different instantiations even if the behavior ends up being identical (and sometimes it won't be e.g., with static template members). Especially with heavy use of `auto` this can definitely crop up and be confusing: I wouldn't want the way an object was initialized to be permanently reflected in its type.